# How to set a value in mysql to NULL using a variable?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to set a variable to NULL if it's empty (after a form input) and update my db with it, but it keeps putting 0 in the field insted of NULL. (field is set to integer/NULL) I also tried $eloleg = "NULL" but that didn't work either.

```
        if (!empty($_POST["eloleg"])) {
            $eloleg = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["eloleg"]);
        }
        else {
            $eloleg = NULL;
        }

        mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE $table SET eloleg='$eloleg' WHERE date='$eredeti_date'");
```

Comment: Use parameter binding. Otherwise, you're open to SQL injection. Null values should not be quoted, but the binding will take care of that for you.

Comment: what's the db schema and does it accept NULL values? Plus a major problem here is that you're mixing MySQL APIs and we don't know which one you're using to connect with.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted to do this:

```
$eloleg = 'NULL';

mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE $table SET eloleg=$eloleg WHERE date='$eredeti_date'");
```

But as others have said, you should use a parametrized API to build your query, to avoid SQL injection as well as formatting pitfalls.

Comment: I think you missed a semi-colon after the first statement

Comment: and about the OP mixing APIs ;-) which is probably why it's failing them in the first place or is contributing to it.

Comment: @luweiqi I'm not a PHP person by training, but I could see that `NULL` was being escaped by quotes in the actual query, which is clearly wrong.

Comment: I think the main problem lies in that the OP's using `mysql_*` functions with `mysqli_*` functions, which won't work

Comment: There is no question about which API OP's using to connect because OP states in the question that the value DOES get updated to 0. If OP was connecting using the wrong API you would have issues, but the value does actually change, and so it's safe to assume OP can connect

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys, I'm not all that worried about security as this will only run on my own machine (WAMP server) and only a few people will have access to it. Could you elaborate what exactly am I mixing up?

Comment: @phpnoob I'm also a PHP noob, but I can see from a glance that you are using the `mysql_real_escape_string()` function from one API alongside the `mysqli_query()` function from another API.  Don't do this, as it can cause problems.

Comment: @phpnoob I hate when people say *"I'm not that far along..."* or *"This site will not be public..."* or *"It's only for school, security doesn't matter..."*. If teachers and professors are not talking about security from day one, they're doing it wrong. Challenge them. They're teaching sloppy and dangerous coding practices which students will have to unlearn later. I also hate when folks say, *"I'll add security later..."* or *"Security isn't important now..."* or *"Ignore the security risk..."*. If you don't have time to do it right the first time, when will you find the time later?

Comment: I've changed all my mysql to mysqli functions but I'm still getting 0 in my db insted of NULL and using eloleg=$eloleg insted of eloleg='$eloleg' in the query is giving me a syntax error.

Comment: At this point this question is such a mess that I think you should ask a new question.

Comment: Na, no point man, I will just get more advices on security wich I don't need. I will make a workaround with more elseif's insted. It's ugly, but it works.